# SMTP Server settings error

Tags: joomla-4.x, emails

I have tested with the Exact same settings on both my local joomla website and the live one.

rex-topia.com [Live]

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Locally [localhost]

```
Message
The email was sent to name@doman.com using SMTP. You should check that you've received the test email.
```

With these settings. [From GoDaddy's mail service]

```
SMTP Host           :: smtpout.secureserver.net
SMTP Port           :: 465
SMTP Security       :: SSL/TLS
SMTP Authentication :: YES

SMTP Username       :: name@domain.com
SMTP Password       :: **SECRET**
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

So I found a fix, I just used CPanels email smpt service.